# Rails doesn't update nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I create an application, which is basically a character creator for an RPG with interactive and dynamic forms. I use Rails 5.0.0.1, and I cannot update my form properly. The base model updates well, but all nested don't.

So, I have

```
class Character < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attr4characters, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attr4characters, allow_destroy: true
end
```

and

```
class Attr4character < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character
end
```

which represent a character and a set of his attributes. Each record in Attr4character is a different attribute.

The Show view is simple:

```
...
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :character_type %>
  <%= f.select(:character_type, options_for_select(["Zhong Lung", "Shih", "Hsien", "Garou", "Technocrat"])) %>
</div>

  <% f.object.attr4characters.each do |attr| %>
    <%= f.fields_for attr do |attr_f| %>
      <div class="field">  
        <%= attr_f.label "Field name" %>
        <%= attr_f.text_field :field_name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">  
        <%= attr_f.label "Field value" %>
        <%= attr_f.text_field :field_value %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
...
```

And finally my characters_controller:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @character.update(character_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @character, notice: 'Character was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @character }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @character.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def set_character
      @character = Character.find(params[:id])
    end

    def character_params
      params.require(:character).permit(:id, :name, :player, :description, :character_type, attr4characters_attributes: [:id, :character_id, :field_name, :field_value])
    end
```

So, I have a form, which correctly display a character and all set of his attributes. When I update a character field (like :description), it is normally updated. When I update any nested field, Rails says that character is successfully updated and nothing changes! I searched with Google, and I found a lot of problems with nested attributes in Rails forms, but none of the recipes worked for me. I even encountered opinions that it is a bug in Rails 4, but I use 5th version...

Please, advice on the topic. Is it a bug really? Or am I doing something wrong? I'm new on Rails, so I don't exclude that possibility. :)

By the way, in the server's log I found that there is warning about attr4characters.

```
Processing by CharactersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"\u2713", "authenticity_token"=>"xeYyIRc13YiOk29v18rFM6Oh5OHRRuPpSKEQuIHE/U4uhANEF7TwMp8mb6hv6L7mUAm5MngAuyFayHcWV/Vvbw==", "character"=>{"name"=>"Ray", "player"=>"111", "description"=>"A Zhong Lung suicider", "character_type"=>"Hsien", "attr4character"=>{"field_name"=>"Gift1", "field_value"=>"Sense Wyrm"}}, "commit"=>"Update Character", "id"=>"3"}
  Character Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "characters".* FROM "characters" WHERE "characters"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: attr4character
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "characters" SET "character_type" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "characters"."id" = ?  [["character_type", "Hsien"], ["updated_at", 2016-09-13 14:39:10 UTC], ["id", 3]]
   (24.3ms)  commit transaction
```

But attr4characters are permitted in the characters_controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is telling you that it is ignoring all the `attr4character` attributes. Your `permit` code is correct as is your model, but your view doesn't match them. You should be doing

```
f.fields_for :attr4characters do |attr_f|
  ...
end
```

And let rails handle iterating over the association. This will also ensure that attributes are named correctly (so they will be allowed through by your whitelist)

Comment: That... was...ugh, thank you. So I need not iterate through f.object.attr4characters manually...